# Strange Behavior When Using PHP to Generate XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am encountering some very strange behavior in php/mysql. I currently have a database of locations with name, address, lat, lng, and type values.

I am using the following code to generate xml from the database

```
<?php
require("dbinfo.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
    $xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
    return $xmlStr; 
} 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) 
{
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) 
{
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) 
{
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if($row['lat'] != 0 && $row['lng'] !=0)
    {
        // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
        echo '<marker ';
        echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
        echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
        echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
        echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
        echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
        echo '/>';
    }
}
// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

The code appears to work, but only when it is in the mood. It occasionally generates the appropriate XML, but usually it does nothing at all, returning a blank page. I have never seen such behavior, does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am running this locally on MAMP if that is of any help. Anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

The @mysql_fetch_assoc($result) supresses sql errors.  You might have some slight issue that is being ignored.  change it to just mysql_fetch_assoc($result) and see whats happening.